# Swift - CoreData persisting after deleting until recompile

Tags: swift

I am trying to use CoreData to save my user data. However, the deleted data does not get updated, even when I save the context. Only upon another compile of the app will the data show correct.

I have searched online for this answer, and multiple suggested putting **appDelegate.saveContext()**. However, even after this it does not work.

Example: I am signed in as User 1. User 1 signs out. User 2 logs in. User 1's data is still being displayed.

Delete:

```
func deleteCoreData(){
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    do
      {
        try context.execute(deleteRequest)
        
      } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
      }
    appDelegate.saveContext()
}
```

Read:

```
func retrieveUserData() -> [String: String]{
    var arr = [String: String]()
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
        do {
            let results = try context.fetch(fetch)
            
            print("Fetching: ", results)
            for result in results {
                arr["name"] = result.name
                arr["schoolName"] = result.schoolName
                arr["school"] = result.school
                arr["programCode"] = result.programCode
                arr["classOf"] = result.classOf
                arr["username"] = result.userId
                arr["programName"] = result.programName
                arr["username"] = result.username
                arr["userId"] = result.userId
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Cannot retrieve")
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

Create

```
func createNewCoreUser(login: String, data: [String: String]) {
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        print("CoreData has been created")
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context) else { return }
        let newValue = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: context)
        newValue.setValue(login, forKey: "userId")
        newValue.setValue(data["name"], forKey: "name")
        newValue.setValue(data["classOf"], forKey: "classOf")
        newValue.setValue(data["programCode"], forKey: "programCode")
        newValue.setValue(data["school"], forKey: "school")
        newValue.setValue(data["schoolName"], forKey: "schoolName")
        newValue.setValue(data["programName"], forKey: "programName")
        newValue.setValue(data["username"], forKey: "username")
        do {
            try context.save()
            
            (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.changeRootViewController(mainTabBarController)
            
        } catch {
            print("Storing data Failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you displaying the data?

Comment: I'm displaying it in a tableview. I edited the code above for retrieving the data. When I print the data, the old User shows up.

Comment: Is this one or many users you are dealing with? If it’s only one then don’t use batch delete, if it’s many then you manually need to refresh your managed context, see for instance [this article](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/nsbatchdeleterequest-core-data/)

Comment: After reading the question more carefully :) it is clear you are dealing with one user so skip the batch delete and delete only one user using `context.delete(user)` instead. That way the user object will be properly removed also from memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. After logging out and signing in, viewDidLoad does not run, so it doesn't run my Retrieve function.